Saving GDALRaster in RasterField using GeoDjango
I want to save a raster using GDALRaster and GeoDjango's RasterField.
In my model I defined the field:
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    raster_foo = models.RasterField(null=True)

and I have a buffer that holds a tiff:
read_ = tiff_.read()
r = GDALRaster(read_)  # also tried: GDALRaster(read_, write=False)

i then try to save the raster like so:
SomeModel.objects.create(raster_foo=r)

this is the error I get:
GDAL_ERROR 6: b'Cannot extended in-memory file whose ownership was not transferred'
ERROR:django.contrib.gis:GDAL_ERROR 6: b'Cannot extended in-memory file whose ownership was not transferred'
GDAL_ERROR 1: b'_tiffWriteProc:Success'
ERROR:django.contrib.gis:GDAL_ERROR 1: b'_tiffWriteProc:Success'
GDAL_ERROR 1: b'TIFFWriteDirectoryTagData:IO error writing tag data'
ERROR:django.contrib.gis:GDAL_ERROR 1: b'TIFFWriteDirectoryTagData:IO error writing tag data'
GDAL_ERROR 1: b'TIFFAdvanceDirectory:/vsimem/41b88e48-8bb9-44e3-badd-c200cad7adca: Error fetching directory count'
ERROR:django.contrib.gis:GDAL_ERROR 1: b'TIFFAdvanceDirectory:/vsimem/41b88e48-8bb9-44e3-badd-c200cad7adca: Error fetching directory count'
GDAL_ERROR 1: b'TIFFFetchDirectory:/vsimem/41b88e48-8bb9-44e3-badd-c200cad7adca: Can not read TIFF directory count'
ERROR:django.contrib.gis:GDAL_ERROR 1: b'TIFFFetchDirectory:/vsimem/41b88e48-8bb9-44e3-badd-c200cad7adca: Can not read TIFF directory count'
GDAL_ERROR 1: b'TIFFReadDirectory:Failed to read directory at offset 19138'
ERROR:django.contrib.gis:GDAL_ERROR 1: b'TIFFReadDirectory:Failed to read directory at offset 19138'

My model actually has more fields with standard django model fields and saving does succeed but the raster field seems to be empty afterwards.
I do not understand the error message.
How fo I fix it?
